# tomcat server is not starting

Tags: tomcat, java, mac

my tomcat server in my mac ,the terminal is showing tomat started,but when is run the local host in the browser it says webpage not found ,but when I try to shutdown the tomcat it is throwing following error
when i start the tomcat i get the message:\n

```
$ ./startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE: /Users/prabu-pt1927/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.4 
Using CATALINA_HOME: /Users/prabu-pt1927/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.4 
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Users/prabu-pt1927/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/temp 
Using JRE_HOME: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home 
Using CLASSPATH: /Users/prabu-pt1927/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Users/prabu-pt1927/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

when i shutdown the tomcat i am getting this...

```
$ ./shutdown.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE: /Users/prabu-pt1927/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.4 
Using CATALINA_HOME: /Users/prabu-pt1927/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.4 
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Users/prabu-pt1927/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/temp 
Using JRE_HOME: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home 
Using CLASSPATH: /Users/prabu-pt1927/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Users/prabu-pt1927/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.4/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Feb 06, 2018 12:22:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer SEVERE: Could not contact [localhost:[8005]]. Tomcat may not be running. 
Feb 06, 2018 12:22:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer SEVERE: Catalina.stop: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)     
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)  
  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)   
  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)   
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:492)    
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)``
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:406)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
```

when i run the same server with java - 9.0.4 ,it works without any issue but when i use java - 1.8. it throws this error.